# recursive binary search of a sorted sublist

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search

I am trying to implement a recursive binary search algorithm which takes 4 arguments, a list, first, the integer index of the first item in the sorted sub-sequence, last, the integer index of the last item in the sorted sub-sequence and a target which will be compared to the values stored in the list.

The algorithm needs to return the position of the target within the sorted sub-sequence (if it exists) and if not return the position in which it should be placed within the sorted sub-sequence.

Here's what I have thus far;

```
def binary_search(a_list, first, last, target):
    subMidpoint = (first + last) // 2
    if a_list[subMidpoint] == target:
        return subMidpoint
    else:
        if target < a_list[subMidpoint]:
            last = subMidpoint -1
            return binarySearch(a_list, first, last, target)
        else:
            first = subMidpoint +1
            return binarySearch(a_list, first, last, target)
    return first
```

I am struggling to wrap my head around how it will return the position if the item does not exist, any help would be greatly appreciated. The code currently compiles however is returning 'None' rather than an index position.

Many Thanks in advance.

Edit;

Thanks all for your help, I have managed to alter the final clause and it has passed some tests however it fails when the target is less than the smallest value in *first* and when the target is greater than the value in *last*.

Here's the altered final clause.

```
    else:
    if target < a_list[subMidpoint]:
        last = subMidpoint -1
        return binary_search(a_list, first, last, target)
    else:
        first = subMidpoint +1
        return first
```

Comment: If you get to a point in the process where there are only two items left and they are not the target then the target's sorted position would probably be between those positions.

Comment: Note that the recursion here is broken. The function is called `binary_search`, but the recursive call is to a function called `binarySearch`. Unfortunately when you fix it, you'll get a max recursion error when the item isn't in the list, because there's no terminal condition in that case. If you figure out the terminal condition, you will also have answered your own question. It's always a good idea to go through the process by hand yourself a few times!

Comment: There is a `bisect` module in Python's standard library. No need to reinvent this wheel.

Comment: Strictly speaking, binary search only works for arrays in O(logn). If you have a (linked) list then scanning the sublist O(n) is the best solution.

Comment: @maraca Strictly speaking this is irrelevant here as `list` in Python isn't implemented as a linked list. :-)

Comment: @BlackJack So a Python list is actually a vector... I respect that, but it is still bad naming, when we talk about a list in computer science we usually mean linked lists which allow to insert a new list node after another one in O(1) (if we already have a pointer to the node after which we want to insert) and doesn't need shifting like arrays.

Comment: @maraca A Python list is actually a list. It's definitely not a vector because vectors have a fixed size. In Scheme.☺ When we talk about lists in CS we usually talk about an [abstract data type or interface for a list or sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)).  It provides operations such as appending elements at the end, asking for it's length, and so on. And that's what Python's `list` type does. Or a `List` declaration in Java doesn't say if it will be a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @maraca Oh, and `list.append()` in Python is also amortized O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have your answer in your description: if you get down to adjacent items, say positions 5 and 6, and you haven't found the item, then it would be inserted between those two.  Since list indices grow to the upper end, you'd return the higher of the two -- `6`, in this case.

Thus, your logic would be in your last clause

```
else:
    if subMidpoint == first:
        return last
    else:
        first = subMidpoint +1
        return binarySearch(a_list, first, last, target)
```

- Drop that `return first` at the bottom; you should *not* be able to reach that statement.
- Learn the `elif` keyword; your program will be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thanks everyone. Not the cleanest solution but it works.

```
def binary_search(a_list, first, last, target):
subMidpoint = (first + last) // 2
if target < a_list[first]:
    return first
elif target > a_list[last]:
    return last +1
elif a_list[subMidpoint] == target:
    return subMidpoint
elif target < a_list[subMidpoint]:
    last = subMidpoint -1
    return binary_search(a_list, first, last, target)
else:
    first = subMidpoint +1
    return first
```